# How to send POST request?

Tags: urllib, python-2.x, httplib

I found this script online:

```
import httplib, urllib
params = urllib.urlencode({'number': 12524, 'type': 'issue', 'action': 'show'})
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Accept": "text/plain"}
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("bugs.python.org")
conn.request("POST", "", params, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
302 Found
data = response.read()
data
'Redirecting to <a href="http://bugs.python.org/issue12524">http://bugs.python.org/issue12524</a>'
conn.close()
```

But I don't understand how to use it with PHP or what everything inside the params variable is or how to use it. Can I please have a little help with trying to get this to work?

Comment: Post request is just post request, regardless what's on server side.

Comment: This sends a POST request. Then the server responds with 302 (redirect) headers to your POST. What is actually wrong?

Comment: This script doesn't look python3.2 compat

Comment: python3 equivalent of this example might be: http://pastebin.com/Rx4yfknM

Comment: What I will suggest is install firefox's `live http header` addon and than open your url in firefox and see the `request/response` of url in `live http header` addon than you will understand what `params and headers` do in your code.

Comment: I like the combination of statements "I don't understand how to use it with PHP" and "I am using Python 3.2" in the original text  =D

Answer (score 491, accepted):

If you really want to handle with HTTP using Python, I highly recommend [Requests: HTTP for Humans](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/). The POST quickstart adapted to your question is:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.post("http://bugs.python.org", data={'number': '12524', 'type': 'issue', 'action': 'show'})
>>> print(r.status_code, r.reason)
200 OK
>>> print(r.text[:300] + '...')

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>
Issue 12524: change httplib docs POST example - Python tracker

</title>
<link rel="shortcut i...
>>>
```

Comment: I cannot get the same result as you did above. I wrote another issue number on the page and then run the script but I could not see the Issue number on the result.

Comment: for the record: a working code recently for me, data={'@number': '12524', '@type': 'issue', '@action': 'show'}

Comment: How to get json result?

Comment: If you need to send a JSON object you should do: `json={'number': 12524...` instead of `data=...`

Comment: why does the answer say "If you really want to handle with HTTP using Python"? is it a bad idea to handle HTTP requests? if so, why? can anyone explain please?

Comment: In some dialects of English, that use of "really" could mean "properly" or "truly" - i.e., this is the full, serious, proper way to handle HTTP with Python

Comment: I think they meant to clarify the context since OP asked something about PHP

Answer (score 189):

This is a solution without any external pip dependencies, but works only in Python 3+ (Python 2 won't work):

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = 'https://httpbin.org/post' # Set destination URL here
post_fields = {'foo': 'bar'}     # Set POST fields here

request = Request(url, urlencode(post_fields).encode())
with urlopen(request) as response:
    json = response.read().decode()
print(json)
```

Sample output:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "foo": "bar"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity", 
    "Content-Length": "7", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "Python-urllib/3.3"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "127.0.0.1", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Answer (score 39):

You can't achieve POST requests using `urllib` (only for GET), instead try using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) module, e.g.:

Example 1.0:

```
import requests

base_url="www.server.com"
final_url="/{0}/friendly/{1}/url".format(base_url,any_value_here)

payload = {'number': 2, 'value': 1}
response = requests.post(final_url, data=payload)

print(response.text) #TEXT/HTML
print(response.status_code, response.reason) #HTTP
```

---

Example 1.2:

```
>>> import requests

>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}

>>> r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
>>> print(r.text)
{
  ...
  "form": {
    "key2": "value2",
    "key1": "value1"
  },
  ...
}
```

Example 1.3:

```
>>> import json

>>> url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
>>> payload = {'some': 'data'}

>>> r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Comment: Thanks. data=json.dumps(payload) is the key for my usecase

Comment: replace "data" with "json" would also do the trick

Answer (score 23):

Use `requests` library to GET, POST, PUT or DELETE by hitting a REST API endpoint. Pass the rest api endpoint url in `url`, payload(dict) in `data` and header/metadata in `headers`

```
import requests, json

url = "bugs.python.org"

payload = {"number": 12524, 
           "type": "issue", 
           "action": "show"}

header = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "Accept": "text/plain"} 

response_decoded_json = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=header)
response_json = response_decoded_json.json()
 
print(response_json)
```

Comment: This code has issues with indentation and the header param name.

Comment: `headers` parameter is wrong and also we have not any json here. We should use `json.dumps(pauload)`

Comment: Thanks @xilopaint and ArashHatami for the syntax error. Corrected now.

Answer (score 6):

Your data dictionary conteines names of form input fields, you just keep on right their values to find results. 
[form view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ueoy.png)
Header configures browser to retrieve type of data you declare.
With requests library it's easy to send POST:

```
import requests

url = "https://bugs.python.org"
data = {'@number': 12524, '@type': 'issue', '@action': 'show'}
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept":"text/plain"}
response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

More about Request object: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a module you have to install like `requests`, and your use case is very basic, then you can use `urllib2`

```
urllib2.urlopen(url, body)
```

See the documentation for `urllib2` here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the request library to make a post request.
If you have a JSON string in the payload you can use json.dumps(payload) which is the expected form of payload.

```py
    import requests, json
    url = "http://bugs.python.org/test"
    payload={
        "data1":1234,'data2':'test'
    }
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
    print(response.text , response.status_code)
```