# How to alter website dropdown menus in Python

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I'm trying to right a piece of code that allows me to automatically categorize certain transactions on Mint.com. I want to alter the right-most dropdown fields. I went through the source code on the site, but I'm not sure what to look for, or how these types of menus work and how to change them. Could someone please point me in the right direction: (What should I research? what should I be looking for in the source code etc.) Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Try using the element inspector on chrome Dev tools to see what the code is behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change its value upon submitting. So you need to see the form action method (it will be probably POST) then you have to think how to send the data to the site from your code. There is some info :

[How to send POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322430/how-to-send-post-request)

You can probably send the data in the dictionary as is explained there.