# How to pass parameter to POST request in python

Tags: python, api, rest, post

Folks,

I am new to python and working on REST API in python. I am facing issue in below scenario where I don't understand how to pass the parameter.

```
Request URL:URL/xyz/api/pqr/
Request method:POST
Params - "test"
Response - {"apps":[], ...., "users": []}
```

I tried standard ways of passing parameter in json and directly to URL but did not work.

edit - I was searching on this and came across this URL - [Parameter Binding in Web API](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/parameter-binding-in-web-api)

Following is a valid HTTP POST request in the fiddler for the above action method.

[image]

It is for .net platform but I don't see same option in python. Is there any way we can do it in python?

Thanks,
Prashant

Comment: Are you creating the api, or are you trying to access it?

Comment: Which library or framework do you use ? Do you have some code example ?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322430/how-to-send-post-request

Comment: @Dash - Thanks for your comment. I am consuming API

Comment: @L. Quastana - Thanks for your comment. I'm using code like below.
response = requests.post(self.hostname + '/xyz/api/pqr/',
       auth=HttpNtlmAuth(self.username, self.password),
                         headers=self.headers,
                         data=json.dumps(data))

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) package.

You could do something like:

```py
import requests

r = requests.post(url, data=data)

print(r.text)   # The response
```

Answer (score 0):

Use request package
like

```
import requests
        r = requests.post('/xyz/api/pqr/', params=Params)
```

Comment: Thank for your prompt response. I tried this but it did not work. 

`code`
#params = (name)
#params = name
params = ('name',name)

response = requests.post(self.hostname + '/xyz/api/pqr/',
                         auth=HttpNtlmAuth(self.username, self.password),
                         headers=self.headers,
                         params=params)