# Access POST response AccessToken Header

Tags: python, json, http, python-requests

I am trying to make a POST request to URL , to authenticate myself ( can't share the URL as it is for work). The authentication worked and I got the token access. However , I need to extract the token access header to use it in other function , I don't want to copy the token and paste it .

So , I tried to do this :

```
response = requests.post(url, data = dic,json={'key':'value'}) # dic is my username and password 
token =response.request.headers['AccessToken']
```

But it is still running , I did not get an error or any output ( I am using Jupyter Notebook)

```
response = requests.post(url, data = dic) # this one works fine but it does not meet the requirement
```

**Additional clarification :**
I am asking the user for (username and password) , then I place them into dic which I pass into the POST request.

**Example of Server Response :**

{"Result":{"AccessToken":"#####="},"Success":true,"Message":"","ErrorCode":""}

Is there other way to access the AccessToken header of the server response ?

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322430/how-to-send-post-request)

Comment: @baduker I feel like you didn't read the question

Comment: @baduker , not it does not .

Comment: So, `data` and `json` do equivalent things... Certainly you dont want both. But also accessing `response.request` seems odd if you want headers from the response (you already sent the request without any headers set)

Comment: @onecricketeer, I am sending the request with username and password as input from user (dic) then I am passing the dic in the post request .. but I want to extract certain header from the server response (AccessToken )

Comment: I understood that, but 1) if you did `dic.update({'key':'value'})` and `post(url, json=dic)`, that would suffice, and as mentioned, I think you're accessing the headers incorrectly, but its also not clear why that would hang. You also wouldn't get output in a cell that only assigned the response variable, so try printing anything there

Comment: @onecricketeer , I have been accessing the headers in the wrong way .. I added server response example , can you please check it out ?

Comment: Those dont look like headers... How are you getting that output? Is that `response.text`? If so, how about `response.json()["Result"]["AccessToken"]`

Comment: @onecricketeer , Thank you so much that worked ... really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You need to *check* that there is a header containing an access token in your response.headers dict. You'll probably want to look for an `Authorization` header, which you'll need to extract the actual token from. In the cases that I'm aware of, that header contents will be

```
"Authorization": "Bearer encoded-access-token-goes-here"
```

so you'd check

```py
    if "Authorization" in response.headers:
        token = response.headers["Authorization"].split()[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Example of Server Response :

> ```
> {"Result":{"AccessToken":"#####="},"Success":true,"Message":"","ErrorCode":""}
> ```

Since that is a *response*, and not a header, you want something like

```
token = None
try:
    token = response.json()["Result"]["AccessToken"]
except KeyError:
    print("No token found")
    print(response.text)
```