# How to send a post requests in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-mining, data-extraction

I want to scrape data from this link
https://www.orpha.net/consor/cgi-bin/ClinicalLabs_Diagnostictest.php?lng=EN&search=ClinicalLabs_Diagnostictest_TechPurpose

I want to use filter by country wise but the url is not changed when I filter it
and in the network tab I see a post requests is sent to this url with data and params
How can I send a post requests with correct data and params. Please Guide me
And also here is my code which I try to send a post request

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.orpha.net/consor/cgi-bin/ClinicalLabs_Diagnostictest.php?lng=EN&search=ClinicalLabs_Diagnostictest_TechPurpose'
data = {'checkFilterLgnBox_AU':'AU'}
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322430/how-to-send-post-request)

Comment: please describe the issue with the provided code?

Comment: I did not get the required data

Answer (score 0):

The address shouldn't return a modified address on your POST. Is there some kind of documentation on the API?

```
https://www.orpha.net/consor/cgi-bin/ClinicalLabs_Diagnostictest.php?lng=EN&search=ClinicalLabs_Diagnostictest_TechPurpose&checkFilterLgnBox_AU=AU
```

This works but this just changes the website activating the checkbox. So it's actually just some state handling for this page.