# Send post request with multiple data files and strings in python script

Tags: python, post, http-post

Im trying to send a post request I need to upload 2 files and some other strings and integers, what is the best way to do this from inside a python script?

I can use curl in the bash terminal and it works but not sure how to format it for a python script?

There are multiple variables that have been defined earlier in the script

```
os.system(r"curl -F ''file=@./'+  t + '.files/' + t + '.png'' -F ''info=@./' +  t + '.files/info.txt'' -F ''name=' + name' -F ''description=' + description' -F ''type=' + reso' -F 'source=' + source' -F 'live=' + live' + url + API")
```

variables are t, name, description, reso, source, live, URL and API

how do I send a post request in python? I came across answers that suggest importing requests but if my file path has a variable in it what syntax would I use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322430/how-to-send-post-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most ideal way would be this:

```
import requests

url = "{YOUR URL}"

payload={}
files=[
  ('file',('filename',open('/pathtofile/filename','rb'),'application/{FILE_TYPE}'))
]
headers = {
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

For multiple variables within your filepath, you can simply concat two or more strings, just define your variables and concat them in the filepath and you'd be good to go.

Like:

```
folder = "abc"
filepath = "C:/Users/xyz/" + abc
```

You can concat as many strings as you'd like. And therefore, inside the `files` list, you can simply replace the string inside open() function with your filepath variable, so your files list would become:

```
files=[
  ('file',('filename',open(filepath,'rb'),'application/{FILE_TYPE}'))
]
```

Comment: so would i use something like this for payload? payload = {'somekey': 'somevalue'}, what would the syntax be if somevalue is a variable?

Comment: For query variables you can simply add ?variable1=data&variable2=data and so on.

For actual payloads, yes, that would be the correct syntax

Comment: thanks it all worked out, I had to open multiple files using this syntax files = {'file': open(file1, 'rb'), 'file2': open(file2, 'rb')}

Comment: I'm glad it did.