# How to add body parameters in python for requests search api

Tags: python, api, rest, python-requests, html-helper

I have a website that requires login then allows a search api, that's public, it's returning error 405, How do I give parameters in requests.post, since following code isn't working

```
response = requests.post(  
    'https://www.somewebsite.com/api/public/',   
    auth=('asct1@gmail.com', 'Cons')
)
```

Comment: If you are trying to login shouldn't you be using ```requests.post``` method ?

Comment: Yes Actually it was Post only, which was giving 405 error

Comment: Please read this and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322430/how-to-send-post-request

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here 405 means that the method you chose in your case .get(...) is not allowed on the endpoint.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405

You wrote as well that you should make a Post request. So give requests.post(...) a try!

Happy Coding, T!

Comment: Yes Actually it was Post only, which was giving 405 error, I edited the question.. Sorry

Comment: The request should be fine, it is more the configuration of the endpoint you are sending the request to which doesn't allow a post request. Do you mind sharing the code for the endpoint as well?