# How to send a request which includes search box content while scraping a website with search box?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a [website](https://product.influencer.in/price-index) using beautiful soup. For that, while making a request I need to send the Instagram user ID which is supposed to be entered in a search box & scrape the response HTML. How should I send the user ID while sending a request? Thanks.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://product.influencer.in/price-index"
r = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml') 
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322430/how-to-send-post-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple post request to the api to get that data. You'll need to enter your email in the value below

```
import requests

instagramHandles = ['leomessi','cristiano']

URL = "https://team.influencer.in/api/v1/price-index/"
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}

for instagramHandle in instagramHandles:
    payload = {
        'email': "name@email.com",
        'insta_handle': instagramHandle}
    
    jsonData = requests.post(URL, headers=headers, data=payload).json()
    cost_min = jsonData['data']['cost_min']
    cost_max = jsonData['data']['cost_max']
    
    print(f'{instagramHandle}: {cost_min} - {cost_max}')
```

**Output:**

```
leomessi: 5.4 Cr. - 6.5 Cr.
cristiano: 8.5 Cr. - 10.1 Cr.
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242982/discussion-between-yashwanth-ravula-and-chitown88).